# how to convert output.mp3 to mp4 with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

i use this command to merge many mp3 files in a directory:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.mp3; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy ./output.mp3
```

and now i want to convert output.mp3 to mp4 format.
i want that my TV receiver read that mp4.
what can i do?

Comment: my TV receiver can read mp4 files that i downloaded from youtube and mp4 torrent files

Answer (score 8):

## Using an image

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.jpg -i input.mp3 -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black,setsar=1,format=yuv420p" -shortest -fflags +shortest output.mp4
```

This command uses the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) + [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filters to make image fit into 1920x1080, [setsar](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setsar) filter to set a normal Sample Aspect Ratio, then the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter sets the chroma subsampling to YUV 4:2:0 for playback compatibility.

See [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into specific size](https://superuser.com/q/547296) for more info and examples.

## Generating a color background

If you want a plain color background use the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc) filter:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=blue:s=1280x720 -i input.mp3 -shortest -fflags +shortest output.mp4
```

## Adding text

You can add text with the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=blue:s=1280x720 -i input.mp3 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='Your Text':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -shortest -fflags +shortest output.mp4
```

See [Text on video using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624103/) for many more examples.

## Visualization (waveforms, etc)

See [How do I turn audio into video (that is, show the waveforms in a video)?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/9697/)

Comment: Is there a way to use a small pre-encoded video instead of an image and loop it for the duration of MP3 file?

Answer (score 5):

Make a black image in some image editor, save it as `image.jpg` and use this one;

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest output.mp4`

(see [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow))

Comment: it doesn't work.receiver after a long time said "format was not supported"